# ReactJS Limit data on GET

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I pull at least 500 data from my database. Whenever I load the page it takes a long time to load due to the volume of data being pulled. What I want to happen is limit this data up to 20 per page only. Can you help me refactor my codes? and how can I implement pagination?

Here's my code

```
getData = () => {
    var url = 'api'
    var PER_PAGE = 20;
    AppActions.secureAgent('GET', url)
      .then((res) => {
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_ALLDATA,
          payload: res.body.data
        });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your backend code. React does not play role here (not that much). Set `limit` as the query in your fetch statement. Take that limit into consideration on backend.

```
getData = () => {
    var PER_PAGE = 20;
    var url = `/ct-dashboard-api/transactions?limit=${PER_PAGE}`;

    AppActions.secureAgent('GET', url)
      .then((res) => {
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_ALLDATA,
          payload: res.body.data
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: your code works sir but I edited your answer a bit. Thank you